# Can Unity generate two .obb files?

Tags: unity, android

I am porting my Unity console game to android. It is roughly 2.5GB.

Assuming that the size cannot be reduced further, is it possible to have Unity generate two .obb files since the limit for each is 2GB? Right now it seems to only produce one 2.5GB .obb, but from my understanding, it is possible to have up to two .obb files.

The files are AssetBundles located in StreamingAssets.

I really didn't want to use Play Asset Delivery, but if I must, then it still has a global limit of 2GB. Therefore I would have to put some of my bundles in StreamingAssets, and some in Asset Bundles, which doesn't sound very ideal.

Comment: Have you considered switching to the newer Addressables system? I'm not sure if it would address your issue, but it might. Otherwise, the easiest solution is to reduce texture export resolutions and audio quality (e.g. export audio clips as mono, reduce bitrate). Texture's don't need to be as high-res on a 4-inch screen, and many phones output sound in mono unless the player is using headphones.

Comment: Another consideration is that some players simply won't want to download a 2.5GB game, either because of how long it will take or because they don't want to give up that much storage space on their phone. Smaller size means more downloads.

Comment: Isn't Addressables ultimately still AssetBundles under the hood anyway? Unless I was hosting them in my own CDN I think they'd still end up either in an .obb file or in the main apk. Also it's already a downgraded version of the Switch/PS4 version which was about 3.5GB, there's not a lot more I can do without the quality finally being noticeably terrible.

Comment: I kept Cognizer under the limit specifically to avoid obb hassles. :/